# MySQL subquery/join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Ok I've got a query that's 90% there, it's just bringing up an error of "unknown column a.UserID in where clause) I've read around trying to sort the problem and found that as SQL processes inside out it won't know what I've set table A to be hence the issue but it's beyond my knowledge and expertise to get it working. I've tried an alternate route with JOINs instead but always come back to the same problem.

The query is:

```
SELECT 
  a.*, 
  (SELECT AVG(c.PlayerTime)
   FROM (
     SELECT PlayerTime 
     FROM elite_highscores b 
     WHERE a.UserID = b.UserID
     ORDER BY PlayerTime ASC LIMIT 10
   ) c
  ) AS avgtime, 
  MIN(PlayerTime) as besttime, 
  MAX(TimeAdded) as time, 
  COUNT(UserID) 
FROM elite_highscores a
WHERE Publish = 'Yes' 
GROUP BY UserID HAVING COUNT(UserID) >= 10 
ORDER BY avgtime ASC
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is select some figures from a highscores table (for users who have over 10 highscores logged) and also calculate the average time (avgtime) but only based upon the last 10 scores of that player, which is what is causing me the issue, everything else seems to be working fine.

The table structure:

```
ScoreID int(16) 
UserID int(10) 
PlayerScore int(16) 
Publish enum('No', 'Hidden', 'Expired', 'Yes')
TimeAdded int(16) 
PlayerIP varchar(18) 
Country varchar(2) 
PlayerTime int(10) 
code varchar(50)
```

Comment: All you need to do is just use the real table name instead of the shorter name you assigned it.

Comment: Your `a.UserID = b.UserID` subquery is nested twice, so it can no longer use the outermost scope as reference, IIRC.

Comment: Andreas, which piece of the query would I replace please? Naltharial yes thought that was the problem but it throws a syntax error if not nested that way, how would I get around it please?

Comment: Mind if you post the `Structure` of your table?

Comment: No problem, it's as follows:

ScoreID  int(16)

UserID  int(10)

PlayerScore     int(16) 

Publish  enum('No', 'Hidden', 'Expired', 'Yes')

TimeAdded  int(16)

PlayerIP  varchar(18)

Country  varchar(2)

PlayerTime  int(10)

code  varchar(50)

Let me know if any more info is needed to make things clearer

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting the structure as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  a.UserID, 
  last10.avgtime, 
  MIN(a.PlayerTime) AS besttime, 
  MAX(a.TimeAdded)  AS time, 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
      elite_highscores a 
  JOIN
      ( SELECT b.UserID,
               AVG(b.PlayerTime) AS avgtime 
        FROM
              ( SELECT DISTINCT UserID
                FROM elite_highscores 
              ) da
          JOIN
              elite_highscores b 
            ON  b.UserID = da.UserID
            AND b.PlayerTime <=
                ( SELECT c.PlayerTime
                  FROM elite_highscores c
                  WHERE c.UserID = da.UserID
                  ORDER BY c.PlayerTime ASC 
                  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9
                ) 
        GROUP BY b.UserID 
      ) last10
    ON last10.UserID = a.UserID 
WHERE a.Publish = 'Yes' 
GROUP BY a.UserID 
ORDER BY avgtime ASC
```

Comment: @user759542: not sure if this is what you need though (about the details).

Comment: @ypercube, be careful `WHERE UserID = a.UserID` may be ambiguous.